Shades from HEX
Just recently I started creating a code to split up colours from a HEX code, given a base colour collection. Now I found a GitHub repository that has this amazing program called mixbox, that super accurately mixes colours. My goal here was just to reverse the code and actually input a colour and get the mix from the starting colour. My accuracy seems however to still be a problem. Now my question here is if someone has some experience with colours in python and how one would be able to actually improve the accuracy of the code to get from the 95-97% level to something more like >99%
I know this is tricky to do, and sometimes the code manages, but sometimes it doesn't. I don't think the iteration count or the "tolerance" is the issue as I have played with those quite a bit and it stays quite the same. Maybe I would need more colours or shades to have an even better result? Could someone give me a comment or proposition on how to tackle this?
I am not sure where to start as maybe the conversion is the issue or the format or the starting material, I would just like to understand the discrepancy and how to solve this in order to get good results.
Here is the code:
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd  # Added pandas for table display
from scipy.optimize import minimize
import mixbox

# Base colors in RGB format

base_colors = {
    "Iron Oxide Red": (155, 47, 28),
    "Iron Oxide Yellow": (204, 145, 5),
    "Iron Oxide Black": (16, 16, 16),
    "Chromium Oxide Green": (95, 133, 59),
    "Ultramarine Blue": (4, 55, 242),
    "Zinc Oxide": (243, 244, 247),
}

# Convert base colors to latent space using mixbox

base_latents = {name: mixbox.rgb_to_latent(color) for name, color in base_colors.items()}

def hex_to_rgb(hex_color):
    hex_color = hex_color.lstrip('#')
    return tuple(int(hex_color[i:i+2], 16) for i in (0, 2, 4))

def rgb_to_hex(rgb_color):
    return '#{:02x}{:02x}{:02x}'.format(int(rgb_color[0]), int(rgb_color[1]), int(rgb_color[2]))

def mix_colors_in_latent_space(proportions, base_latents):
    z_mix = [0] * mixbox.LATENT_SIZE

    for i in range(mixbox.LATENT_SIZE):
        for latent, proportion in zip(base_latents.values(), proportions):
            z_mix[i] += proportion * latent[i]

    # Convert mixed latent vector back to RGB
    rgb_mix = mixbox.latent_to_rgb(z_mix)
    return rgb_mix

def color_similarity(rgb1, rgb2):
    """Calculate the similarity percentage between two RGB colors."""
    distance = np.linalg.norm(np.array(rgb1) - np.array(rgb2))
    max_distance = np.linalg.norm(np.array([255, 255, 255]))  # Max distance in RGB space
    similarity = 100 * (1 - distance / max_distance)
    return similarity

def refine_proportions(target_rgb, initial_proportions, base_latents, tolerance=1e-4, max_iterations=1000):
    current_proportions = np.array(initial_proportions)
    
    for iteration in range(max_iterations):
        current_color = mix_colors_in_latent_space(current_proportions, base_latents)
        similarity = color_similarity(current_color, target_rgb)
        
        if similarity >= (100 - tolerance):
            break
        
        # Adjust each proportion by a small amount and check if it improves the similarity
        for i in range(len(current_proportions)):
            for adjustment in [-0.01, 0.01]:
                adjusted_proportions = np.copy(current_proportions)
                adjusted_proportions[i] += adjustment
                adjusted_proportions = np.clip(adjusted_proportions, 0, 1)
                adjusted_proportions /= np.sum(adjusted_proportions)  

# Ensure proportions sum to 1
                adjusted_color = mix_colors_in_latent_space(adjusted_proportions, base_latents)
                adjusted_similarity = color_similarity(adjusted_color, target_rgb)
                
                if adjusted_similarity > similarity:
                    current_proportions = adjusted_proportions
                    similarity = adjusted_similarity
                    break
    
    final_color_rgb = mix_colors_in_latent_space(current_proportions, base_latents)
    final_similarity = color_similarity(final_color_rgb, target_rgb)
    
    return current_proportions, final_similarity, final_color_rgb

def makeup_matcher(target_hex, base_latents, max_iterations=10000, tolerance=1e-6):
    target_rgb = hex_to_rgb(target_hex)  # Convert HEX to RGB
    
    n_colors = len(base_latents)
    
    # Initial guess: Equal proportions for all colors
    initial_proportions = np.array([1/n_colors] * n_colors)
    
    # Refine proportions iteratively
    best_proportions, final_similarity, final_color_rgb = refine_proportions(
        target_rgb, initial_proportions, base_latents, tolerance=tolerance, max_iterations=max_iterations)
    
    # Convert the final proportions to percentages
    proportions_dict = {name: round(p * 100, 4) for name, p in zip(base_latents.keys(), best_proportions)}
    matched_color_hex = rgb_to_hex(final_color_rgb)
    
    # Create a pandas DataFrame to display the proportions in a table
    df = pd.DataFrame(list(proportions_dict.items()), columns=['Color', 'Percentage'])
    df.set_index('Color', inplace=True)
    
    return df, matched_color_hex, final_similarity

# Example usage
target_hex = "#FAEBDE"
proportions_table, matched_color_hex, similarity = makeup_matcher(target_hex, base_latents)

# Display the proportions table, matched color, and similarity
print(proportions_table)
print("Matched color in HEX:", matched_color_hex)
print(f"Similarity to target color: {similarity:.2f}%")

Play with tolerance, iterations; just use rgb, have additional shades

Note: there is no agreed name of colour (and the contrary). Many names you find are wrong in different contests (also on professional contexts). In any case, you should convert to HSL/HSV which it more similar to eye+brain perception, but still with many exceptions. Check wikipedia about deltaE for formula to check if colours are similar You do not need the super precise one, but you can test the best formula for your purpose..
